# Array: Each User has only one row

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to test an Calendar-System.
The events get loaded successfully, but get displayed in different rows.
How can I just create only one row per user (id) and add the data to that specific row?

Code:

```
foreach($stuArr as $student) {
    $id = $student[0];
    $dates  = $student[1];
    $name  = $student[2];
    $time  = $student[3];
    $state = $student[4];
    
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>".$id."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$name."</td>";
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $days_in_month; $j++) {
        if(in_array($j, $dates))
            echo "<td>".$time."".$state."</t>";
        else 
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    }  

    echo "</tr>";           
}
```

If you need more Code, just say it. I am PHP beginner and dont know which Code you need. But this is the part, where the row is generated.

[image]

Edit:

```
foreach($data as $student) { 
    $id = $student->id;
    $name = $student->name;

    $mark = false;
    foreach($data2 as $cal) {
        if($cal->resource == $id) {
            $start  = new DateTime(substr($cal->start, 0, 10));
            $end    = new DateTime(substr($cal->end, 0, 10));
            //$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
            $end = $end->modify( '+1 day' );
            
            $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
            $period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval ,$end);


            $time = $cal->time;
            $state = $cal->state;

            $dd         = [];
            if($month == $start->format('n')) {
                foreach ($period as $dt) {
                    if($month != $dt->format('n'))
                        break;
                    $dd[]   = $dt->format("j");
                }
                $stuArr[] = [$id, $dd, $name, $time, $state];
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with the array. It has separate entries for each date for the student, instead of one entry with multiple dates in `$dates`.

Comment: @Barmar I updated my code with the Array-Query.

Comment: Does each `date` have a related `time` and `state`???  Or is there only one `time` and `state` per `id`?

Comment: A screenshot is the lowest quality way of presenting your data.  Please [edit] your question to provide a clear [mcve].

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

Make `$stuArr` an associative array that uses the student ID as the key.

Then nest each scheduled item as a nested array in this, and add another loop to find all the items on each date.

I've also changed the code to use associative arrays for the rows, rather than having magic number indexes.

```
<?php
foreach ($data as $student) {
    $id = $student->id;
    $name = $student->name;
    $items = [];
    foreach ($data2 as $cal) {
        if ($cal->resource == $id) {
            $start = new DateTime(substr($cal->start, 0, 10));
            if ($month != $start->format('n')) {
                continue;
            }
            $end = new DateTime(substr($cal->end, 0, 10));
            //$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
            $end = $end->modify('+1 day');

            $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
            $period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

            $time = $cal->time;
            $state = $cal->state;

            $dd = [];
            foreach ($period as $dt) {
                if ($month != $dt->format('n'))
                    break;
                $dd[] = $dt->format("j");
            }
            $items[] = ['days' => $dd, 'time' => $time, 'state' => $state];
        }
    }
    $stuArr[$id] = ['name' => $name, 'items' => $items];
}

foreach ($stuArr as $id => $student) {
    $name = $student['name'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $id . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $name . "</td>";
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $days_in_month; $j++) {
        $date_item = "";
        foreach ($student['items'] as $item) {
            if (in_array($j, $item['days'])) {
                $date_item .= "{$item['time']}{$item['state']}";
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($date_item) {
            echo "<td>$date_item</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        }
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `id` as the index then you can have one row with multiple dates. Instead of this:

```
$stuArr[] = [$id, $dd, $name, $time, $state];
```

Do something like this to append the dates:

```
if(!isset($stuArr[$id])) {
    $stuArr[$id] = ['dates' => $dd, 'name' => $name, 'time' => $time, 'state' => $state];
} else {
    $stuArr[$id]['dates'] = array_merge($stuArr[$id]['dates'], $dd);
}
```

Then to display just use the new indexes:

```
foreach($stuArr as $key => $student) {
    $id    = $student[$key];
    $dates = $student['dates'];
    $name  = $student['name'];
    $time  = $student['time'];
    $state = $student['state'];
    //etc...
```

FYI, you haven't closed the `</td>` correctly in this code:

```
        echo "<td>".$time."".$state."</t>";
```